# Saturn Rings - OpenGL - C++ - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: opengl, visual-c++-2010

I have implemented Saturn Rings using OpenGL/C++. However, the rings doesn't look impressive as it is built using a normal texture. However,  I am seeking for real views and scenes. I would like to have Saturn Rings look like they are real but without using texture to have more control over the view. For example, saturn planet has some moons orbiting between the rings and I would like to show these moons to give more realistic view of the planet.  I've tried the code given in "Texturing and Modeling, A procedural approach" book, but it requires a lot of changes that I don't know how to implement in visual Studio 2010.

I have seen some ideas about bulding Saturn rings using dots, cyrcles and shaders. I am not sure how to do that efficiently.

I really appreciate if someone could provide some code examples shows how to draw Saturn's Rings where they look as real as possible in C++.

Thanks

Comment: I have very little idea what your are talking about. Can you be more concrete? Code examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a ring of 'particles' using instancing. You can see an example here: [Learn OpenGL, instancing](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing)

Comment: Thanks Adrian... I wish there is an easier way to make it work on visual studio.